# Retraining of facebook/bart-large-mnli possible?

Tags: nlp, text-classification, bart

I want to retrain the bart-large-mnli for my own type of datasets and labels. Currently I am using the zero-shot classification for my dataset classification.

```
from transformers import pipeline
classifier = pipeline("zero-shot-classification",
                      model="facebook/bart-large-mnli")
sequence_to_classify = "one day I will see the world"
candidate_labels = ['travel', 'cooking', 'dancing']
classifier(sequence_to_classify, candidate_labels)
#{'labels': ['travel', 'dancing', 'cooking'],
# 'scores': [0.9938651323318481, 0.0032737774308770895, 0.002861034357920289],
# 'sequence': 'one day I will see the world'}
```